# Extract Object Type from Custom PowerShell Object

Tags: powershell

If I have a custom PowerShell Object with int, boolean, and PSCredential, I need to be able to write those out to a location. The easiest solution is to do a foreach loop, but I need to treat PSCredential differently of course. How can I exclude PSCredential from the foreach when writing out all other values?

Custom object is initialized similar to:

```
$myObj = [PSCustomObject]@{
  Value1 = [string]
  Value2 = [int]
  Value3 = $null}
```

Further on in the processing of the script, Value3 is set to Get-Credential and the user is prompted for credentials.

Answer (score 2):

Use `select` to restrict the properties appearing the output:

```
$myObj | select -Property * -ExcludeProperty Value3
```

Note that you **must** use `-Property *` here, otherwise `-ExcludeProperty` won't have any effect.

Answer (score 0):

For a location like a file try

```
"Value1 is {0}, Value2 is {1}" -f $myObj.Value1, $myObj.Value2 |out-file $someFileNameHere
```

Or did I misunderstand your question?

Comment: Yes, I could of course do that -- except when the object contains 20+ properties, that is convoluted. I have 5 PSCredentials and the remainder are other object types that I want to extract, without having to handle each property by hand.

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this help?

```
$array = <array of objects>

$Props = $array[0].psobject.Properties |
Where { $_.TypeNameofValue -ne 'System.Management.Automation.PSCredential' } |
select -ExpandProperty Name

$array | select $Props
```

That should select out all the properties that aren't credentials